# Integral of $((x^2+1)((x-1)^2+1))^{-1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Find $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(2-2x+x^2)}dx$$

So I am going to integrate this using a semicircular contour. Is it safe to say that on the curved part, the integral vanishes? because we have two terms that are of the order $x^2$.  Wouldn't this mean that the Integral that I wish to calculate is equivalent to $2\pi i\sum Res$.  Now the zeros of the denominator are $\pm i$ and $1\pm i$.  However, only $i$ and $1+i$ belong in the semicircle.  Is this part correct so far? Also, how would I calculate the residues at those two points.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you want me to format it better?

Comment: Not any more: it is already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct so far.  To calculate the residue at $i$, multiply by $x-i$, then evaluate at $i$.  So calculate $$\frac1{(x+i)(x^2-2x+2)}$$ at $x=i$, and multiply by $2\pi i$.  Then do the same for $1+i$.

Comment: okay thanks.  I think I see why this works.  Would it be because we clear the denominator for the term $a_{-1}/(x-i)$ in the laurent expansion and the rest of the laurent expansion is 0.  What about the terms before $a_{-1}$? because wouldnt we now have a $a_{-2}/(x-i)$ term?

Comment: An $a_{-2}$ term would be $a_{-2}/(x-i)^2$.  The four factors in the denominator are $(x+i)(x-i)(x-1+i)(x-1-i)$. there is no squared factor.

Comment: but after we multiply by $(x-i)$ doesnt the exponent change to 1 instead of 2?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  If there were an $a_{-2}$, then it was originally $a_{-2}/(x-i)^2$, and the integral of that is $-a_{-2}/(x-i)$, which is zero when evaluated around the closed loop.  It is only $1/(x-i)$, whose integral is $\log(x-i)$, which changes by $2\pi i$ from one end of the loop to the other.

Comment: okay I think I get it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2-2x+2)}=\frac{3-2x}{5(x^2-2x+2)}+\frac{2x+1}{5(x^2+1)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Is what I had so far on the right track?